# Distribution of quantum beating among spectral frequencies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, coherence

Let's imagine that we have 3-level system: ground state $\vert 0 \rangle$ and two excited states $\vert 1 \rangle$, $\vert 2 \rangle$ with similar energies $\hbar \omega _1$ and $\hbar \omega _2$ relative to ground state. Ultrashort (eg. femtosecond) laser pulse is able to produce nonstationary excited state: $\vert \Psi (t) \rangle = c_1 \vert 1 \rangle e^{-i \omega _1 t} + c_2 \vert 2 \rangle e^{-i \omega _2 t}$ that is evolving with time.

My questions are:

1. Should I calculate probability of radiative return to ground state like in stationary case: $P \propto \vert \langle \Psi (t) \vert \mu \vert 0 \rangle \vert ^2$?
2. What are frequencies of emitted photons? $\omega _1$ and $\omega _2$ with intensities proportional to squares of superposition coefficients? Or maybe photons have frequency corresponding to mean energy of nonstationary state?
3. $\vert \langle \Psi (t) \vert \mu \vert 0 \rangle \vert ^2$ has an oscillatory component proportional to $\cos [(\omega _2 - \omega _1)t]$. How those oscillations of intensities are distributed among photons of different frequencies?
4. If there is no emission to ground state but instead nonstationary state is englightened with light resonant with transition to some upper state $\vert 3 \rangle$, is absorption intensity oscillating too?